# Searching and updating hexadecimal values in python

Tags: python, insert

I have a csv file in which one column is of hexadecimal values which is some product no. like '182666828988' , '183a2d4e3a12' I have to take one new product no. and check whether it already exist or not if does I have to update the frequency of product no. if doesn't add a new row in data set with frequency one. what is the most efficient way to do this in python, as i have a very large data set.
Thanx

Comment: Is the file too large to load into memory? Is it sorted by product number? You should probably be using a proper database for this.

Comment: Even sqlite would be better

Comment: proper database is there I have to take data from data base and then do some summarization and update further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's `defaultdict` if you can allow to use an in-memory dict. It will automatically create new entries with zero count if they don't exist.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

freq = defaultdict(int)
freq['182666828988'] += 1
freq['182666828988'] += 1
freq['183a2d4e3a12'] += 1

print(freq)
```

which outputs

```py
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'182666828988': 2, '183a2d4e3a12': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

If your file can fit into RAM - I think you can use a simple python dictionary to resole the problem. Let assume that '182666828988' already appears 5 times, and '183a2d4e3a12' 2 times:

```
table = {}
table['182666828988'] = 5
table['183a2d4e3a12'] = 2

def fun(x):
    if x not in table:
        table[x] = 0
    table[x] += 1

fun('183a2d4e3a12')
fun('124124124124')

print table
```

> {'182666828988': 5, '124124124124': 1, '183a2d4e3a12': 3}

Comment: No. of product no.s are very large so cant assign frequency manually either

Comment: Did you thought to use any map reduce framework for this task? Hadoop or Spark?

Comment: BTW it looks very similar to deduplication problem - to recognize if a given hash value already exists in the hash table, and then ref. counter should be updated or new element should be added to the table. It is broadly researched problem with many papers and patents - so to make it efficiently is not easy at all.

Comment: BTW what is the amount of products? since this is what you need to hold in memory - not the whole data set, so if number of products is less then couple millions the python dictionary will work.

Comment: product is actually cellphones so large no. but millions is fine, but my problem is still not resolved it is ok with some data which can be manually feed but for large set I didnt get how to do it and again  I have to do it on daily basis so I don't wanna run entire code on whole data. So just scan for new data and run accordingly. I hope i am able to explain my problem.

Comment: You are taking data from database, it mean that you can get it on dayly bades, am I right? Then you need a new table that will accumulate all the historical data till today (for each hex key will include its counter) and then ypu will update it by dayly delta on dayly bases.

Comment: Do you need help with such table creation?